# xarray coordinate-dependent computation

Tags: python, python-xarray

I'm using xarray with data for which I have measurements and errors.
I store these along a dimension **moment** in the dataset with coordinates **value** and **variance**.
When I compute for example the mean along a dimension I need values and variances to be treated differently as the former should be combined as

`mean_values = sum(values)/len(values)`

but the latter as

`mean_variance = sum(variances**2)/len(variances)`.

Currently I'm doing this by forming two new datasets and concatinating them. This is very ugly, convoluted and not suited to more complex calculations. I would like to be able to do this kind of operation in one step, perhaps by defining a function taking values and variances as input and then broadcasting the dataset dimension moment onto it.

Given a dataset **q_lp** with dimensions **moment, time, position**:

```
q_lp_av = q_lp.sel(moment='value').mean(dim='time')
q_lp_var = q_lp.sel(moment='variance').reduce(average_of_squares, dim='time')
q_lp = xr.concat([q_lp_common_av, q_lp_common_var], dim='moment')
```

where **average_of_squares** is defined by

```
def average_of_squares(data, axis=None):
    sums = np.sum(data**2, axis=axis)
    if axis:
        return sums/np.shape(data)[axis]**2
    return sums/len(data)**2
```

- What better ways are there to handle this?
- Is it possible to use **xr.apply_ufunc** and a **my_average** function to do this in one step and in-place?
- Should I no be putting theses into one dataset together at all? q_lp is later on combined with other quantities, also with dimensions moment, pos and time, into a DataSet.

I'm grateful for discussion, ideas, tips and links to examples.

Edit:
To clarify, I don't like splitting the DataArray, handling each moment seperately and concatenating them again. I would prefer a possibility to do the following (untested pseudocode for illustration):

```
def multi_moment_average(mean, variance):
    mean = np.average(mean)
    variance = np.sum(variance**2)/len(variance)
    return mean, variance

q_lp.reduce(multi_moment_average, broadcast='moment', dim='time')
```

Minimal working example:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr


def average_of_squares(data, axis=None):
    sums = np.sum(data**2, axis=axis)
    if axis:
        return sums/np.shape(data)[axis]**2
    return sums/len(data)**2


times = np.arange(10)
positions = np.array([1, 3, 5])
values = np.ones((len(times), len(positions))) * (2 + np.random.rand())
variance = np.ones((len(times), len(positions))) * np.random.rand()

q_lp = xr.DataArray(np.array([values, variance]),
                    coords=[['value', 'variance'], times, positions],
                    dims=['moment', 'time', 'position'])

q_lp_av = q_lp.sel(moment='value').mean(dim='time')
q_lp_var = q_lp.sel(moment='variance').reduce(average_of_squares, dim='time')
q_lp = xr.concat([q_lp_av, q_lp_var], dim='moment')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can write your function in an xarray-friendly way, and then call it on your data. i.e.

```
def average_of_squares(data, dim=None):
    sums = (data ** 2).sum(dim)
    return sums/data.count(dim)**2

q_lp_var = q_lp.sel(moment='variance').pipe(average_of_squares, dim='time')
```

Having them concat-ed in the same `DataArray` is fine; it might be a more natural fit for items on a `Dataset`, though.

Does that answer your question?

Edit: re the edited question, I think holding the items in a Dataset rather than a DataArray is most coherent with the data structures. It seems like the mean & variance are two different arrays you want aligned on the same indexes, so a Dataset is ideal

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The re-writing of average_of_squares is interesting and I will look into the use of .pipe, but my main concern was the split operation on q_lp_av and q_lp_var. I will update my question to better reflect this.

Comment: TBC `pipe` is just running a function, this is equivalent: `average_of_squares(q_lp.sel(moment='variance'), dim='time')`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that suits my needs, but am still grateful for more suggestions:

groupby can seperate a Dataset or DataArray along a specified dimension, list thereof creates (key, value) tuples and dict of this has essentially the form of a keyword dictionary. See http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/groupby.html

My current solution thus looks like this:

```
import xarray as xr

def function_applier(data, function, split_dimension=None, **function_kwargs):
    return xr.concat(
                function(
                    **dict(list(data.groupby(split_dimension))),
                    **function_kwargs),
                dim=split_dimension)
```

Now I can define functions taking specific coordinates as inputs which can be written to also work for e.g. numpy arrays.
(MWE using the specific example of my original question here)

```
import numpy as np

def average_of_gaussians(val, var, dim=None): 
    return val.mean(dim), (var ** 2).sum(dim)/var.count(dim)

val = np.random.rand(12).reshape(2,6)
var = 0.1*np.random.rand(12).reshape(2,6)

da = xr.DataArray([val, var],
                  dims=['moment','time','position'],
                  coords=[['val','var'],
                          np.arange(6),
                          ['a','b']])

>>>da
<xarray.DataArray (moment: 2, position: 2, time: 6)>
array([[[0.66233728, 0.71419351, 0.96758741, 0.96949021, 0.94594299,
         0.05080628],
        [0.44005458, 0.64616657, 0.69865189, 0.84970553, 0.19561433,
         0.8529829 ]],

       [[0.02209967, 0.02152369, 0.09181031, 0.00223527, 0.01448938,
         0.01484197],
        [0.05651841, 0.04942305, 0.08250529, 0.04258035, 0.00184209,
         0.0957248 ]]])
Coordinates:
  * moment    (moment) <U3 'val' 'var'
  * position  (position) <U1 'a' 'b'
  * time      (time) int32 0 1 2 3 4 5

>>>function_applier(da,
                 average_of_gaussians,
                 split_dimension='moment',
                 dim='time')
<xarray.DataArray (moment: 2, position: 2)>
array([[0.71839295, 0.61386263],
       [0.001636  , 0.00390397]])
Coordinates:
  * position  (position) <U1 'a' 'b'
  * moment    (moment) object 'val' 'var'
```

Note the input names equal to the coordinates for average_of_gaussians. The different operation on each variable in one function and the lack of references to xarray within it are the properties I am after.